# Plaid API Python

Tags: python-3.x, plaid

I am trying to use plaid-python to load the transaction data for customers. However I am lost with the documentation. I have initiated as per the documentation.

```
    configuration = plaid.Configuration(
        host=plaid.Environment.Sandbox,
        api_key={
            'clientId': PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
            'secret': PLAID_SECRET,
        })
api_client = plaid.ApiClient(configuration)
client = plaid_api.PlaidApi(api_client)
```

However I am lost here, with the public and access tokens. Can someone help me generate the public and access tokens.

Comment: You need to register to use Plaid first -> https://dashboard.plaid.com/signup?email=&referrer_url= - After you get an email, you'll be able to generate your API key data

Comment: https://github.com/plaid/plaid-node/issues/185?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title simply repeats information already in the tags, and says nothing about the content of your question. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the quickstart guide - there's a lot of backend work you need to have up and running before you can begin requesting any data

https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#how-it-works

The public key and access tokens are generated from a local server that you need to set up on your machine.